# Access GlideRecord from within service portal widget

Tags: servicenow

How can I run a Glide query from in a widget? (Service Portal)

This code runs fine in the script-background editor, but it doesn't work in the Server-script section of my widget:

```
var grTask = new GlideRecord('task');
grTask.get('number', "REQ0323232");  // hardcoded good sample
destination_sys_id = grTask.sys_id;
```

When I run the code in Scripts, I get:
`*** Script: sys_id: 0f4d[...]905`

When I run it in the widget, I get:`{}`

To elaborate on my Widget code:

Body HTML template

```
data.destination_sys_id = {{data.destination_sys_id }}
```

Server script

```
(function(){
  var destination_sys_id = "initialized";
  var grTask = new GlideRecord('task');
  grTask.get('number', "REQ0323232");
  destination_sys_id = grTask.sys_id;
  data.destination_sys_id = destination_sys_id;
})()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed a `.toString();` in my server script:

```
(function(){
  var destination_sys_id = "initialized";
  var grTask = new GlideRecord('task');
  grTask.get('number', "REQ0323232");
  destination_sys_id = grTask.sys_id.toString();  // <- note the addition of .toString()
  data.destination_sys_id = destination_sys_id;
})()
```

Another way is to use `grTask.getUniqueValue()` instead of `grTask.sys_id.toString()`.

Also, getters and setters are recommended with GlideRecord, so use `grTask.getValue('sys_id')` instead of `grTask.sys_id.toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

you can add it as c.data.destination_sys_id nad at the time of assigning the value to object always use .toString() in order to stringify the field value.